# Efficient way to process many threads of same Application

Tags: multithreading, performance, sockets

I have a Multi-Client Single-Server application where client and server gets connected through sockets. Client and Server are in different machine.

In client Application, client socket gets connected to server and sends data periodically to server.

In server application server socket listens for client to connect. When a client is connected, new thread is created for client to receive data.

for example: 1 client = 1 thread created by server for receiving data. If its 10000 client, server creates 10000 threads. This seems not good and scalable too.

My Application is in Java.

Is there an alternate method for this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When using windows you could check out this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical [C10K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) problem. There are patterns to solve this, one examples is [Reactor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern)

Java NIO is another way where the incoming request can be processed in non blocking way. See a reference implementation [here](https://github.com/jjenkov/java-nio-server)

Comment: and if your not in java, it's safe to assume there are "selectables" / "async" socket io in other languages. It's though though, especially with secure SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should not need a separate thread for each client. There's a good tutorial [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/12/15/awaiting-socket-operations/) that explains how to use `await` to handle asynchronous socket communication. Once you receive data over the socket you can use a fixed number of threads. The tutorial also covers techniques to handle thousands of simultaneous communications.

---

*Unfortunately given the complexity it's not possible to post the code here, so although link-only answers are frowned upon ...*

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's a perfect candidate for an Erlang/Elixir application. Whatsapp, RabbitMQ...

Erlang processes are cheap and fast to start, Erlang manages the scheduling for you so you don't have to think about the number of threads, CPUs or even machines, Erlang manages garbage collection for each process after you don't need it anymore.

Haskell is slow, Erlang is fast enough for most applications that are not doing heavy calculations and even then you can use it and hand off the heavy lifting to a C process.

What are you writing in?

Comment: My Application is in Java

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use the Actor model, with e.g. Akka or Akka.net. This allows you to create millions of actors that run on e.g. 4 threads. Erlang is a programming language that implements the actor model natively.

However, actors and non-blocking code won't do you much good if you are relying on blocking library calls for backend services that you rely on, such as (the most prominent example in the JVM world) JDBC calls.

There is also a rather interesting approach that Haskell uses, called green threads. It means that the runtime threads are very lightweight and are dynamically mapped to OS threads. It also means that you get a certain amount of scalability "for free", with no need to write non-blocking IO code. It does however require a good IO manager in the runtime to schedule the IO operations efficiently, and GHC Haskell has had a substantial amount of work put into that in recent years.